# Importing AOSP to Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi I tried to import AOSP to Eclipse using the guide in https://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html. 
During project building, I got the following message error "Java heap size". 
I increased the memory settings in eclipse.ini and still the problem exists.
Other error messages that appeared:

- GC overhead limit exceeded,
- Flushing content description cache,
- periodic workspace save,
- unhandled event loop exception,

Please any guidance that can help!

Comment: Disable auto-build projects option in eclipse. You will not need it at all for AOSP.

Comment: aosp is quite huge. importing it all in eclipse with all default options is going to be problematic

Comment: So, what is the alternative tool,

Comment: I need an ide that facilitate tracing the code

Answer (score -1):

The google link above leaves lot to imagination. If you are successful creating a project, any time you build anything using eclipse under AOSP, the main AOSP build breaks.

Please check [Using Eclipse to browse/edit AOSP code](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-eclipse-to-browse-and-edit-aosp.html). This describes a way to create shadow directory of AOSP and use it for Eclipse project. You can edit, browse and debug AOSP code with this project while building code using shell (i.e. terminal window).

If you are working on AOSP, you might want to check [Debugging Android Java Framework](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/debugging-android-java-framework.html) link as well. This talks about debugging your AOSP changes using eclipse.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.